# How to add numbers in a mutable array in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsmutablearray, nsnumber

I am new to iPhone development. I want a Nsmutable array to hold numbers from 1 to 100. How can I do it? How can I implement in a for loop? Is there any other way to hold numbers in array in iPhone?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can only add NSObject subclasses in Cocoa containers.  In your case, you will have to wrap your integers in NSNumber objects:

```
NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray array];
for( int i = 0; i < 100; ++i )
{
   [array addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:i]];
}
```

To extract the values:

```
int firstValue = [[array objectAtIndex:0] intValue];
```

Comment: any idea how we would remove a number added this way if we dont know the index?  im trying to use [array removeObjectIdenticalTo:i]; i have also tried  [array removeObjectIdenticalTo:[i intValue]] and  [array removeObjectIdenticalTo:[NSNumber numberWithInt:i]]

Answer (score 1):

Use an NSNumber object:

```
[NSNumber numberWithInt:1];
```

Comment: I am a newbie, can u give more code,of how u save the values in a array.Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The short hand solution

```
NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray array];
for( int i = 0; i < 100; ++i )
{
   [array addObject:@(i)];
}


int intValue = 10;
NSNumber *numberObj  = @(intValue);
```